# Slow query when adding additional join in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a query to database that takes a lot of time to return results. The query is created through entity framework 6, but I've got the generated query and I'm testing the query in SQL Management Studio.

After make some test I've realized that when I quit a specific table in from the joins the query works in less than one second, if not the query takes more than 30 seconds.

My first idea was that there is no index for the primary key of this table, but the database schema has been created through EF Migrations, so all the primary keys have their proper indexs.

This is the query

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Join4].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Join4].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Join4].[IdServiceType] AS [IdServiceType], 
    [Join4].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Join4].[DescriptionLarge] AS [DescriptionLarge], 
    [Join4].[DescriptionAgency] AS [DescriptionAgency], 
    [Join4].[DescriptionCentral] AS [DescriptionCentral], 
    [Join4].[Pvp] AS [Pvp], 
    [Join4].[PreviousPvp] AS [PreviousPvp], 
    [Join4].[PriceAgency] AS [PriceAgency], 
    [Join4].[PriceProvider] AS [PriceProvider], 
    [Join4].[PriceSamurai] AS [PriceSamurai], 
    [Join4].[IdProvider] AS [IdProvider], 
    [Join4].[IdDestination] AS [IdDestination], 
    [Join4].[IdOrigin] AS [IdOrigin], 
    [Join4].[ExpirationDate] AS [ExpirationDate], 
    [Join4].[DistanceToCenter] AS [DistanceToCenter], 
    [Join4].[Longitude1] AS [Longitude], 
    [Join4].[Latitude1] AS [Latitude], 
    [Join4].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
    [Join4].[ValidationDateStart] AS [ValidationDateStart], 
    [Join4].[ValidationDateEnd] AS [ValidationDateEnd], 
    [Join4].[ExecutionDateStart] AS [ExecutionDateStart], 
    [Join4].[ExecutionDateEnd] AS [ExecutionDateEnd], 
    [Join4].[Nights] AS [Nights], 
    [Join4].[Document] AS [Document], 
    [Join4].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
    [Join4].[Code1] AS [Code], 
    [Join4].[Name1] AS [Name], 
    [Join4].[IdSuperDestination1] AS [IdSuperDestination], 
    [Join4].[Iata1] AS [Iata], 
    [Join4].[Level1] AS [Level], 
    [Join4].[IdDestinationType1] AS [IdDestinationType], 
    [Join4].[TouristInfo1] AS [TouristInfo], 
    [Join4].[Longitude2] AS [Longitude1], 
    [Join4].[Latitude2] AS [Latitude1], 
    [Join4].[Language1] AS [Language], 
    [Join4].[IdCurrency1] AS [IdCurrency], 
    [Join4].[CurrencyName1] AS [CurrencyName], 
    [Join4].[Vaccine1] AS [Vaccine], 
    [Join4].[Visa1] AS [Visa], 
    [Join4].[Embassy1] AS [Embassy], 
    [Join4].[Recommendations1] AS [Recommendations], 
    [Join4].[Id3] AS [Id2], 
    [Join4].[Code2] AS [Code1], 
    [Join4].[Name2] AS [Name1], 
    [Join4].[IdSuperDestination2] AS [IdSuperDestination1], 
    [Join4].[Iata2] AS [Iata1], 
    [Join4].[Level2] AS [Level1], 
    [Join4].[IdDestinationType2] AS [IdDestinationType1], 
    [Join4].[TouristInfo2] AS [TouristInfo1], 
    [Join4].[Longitude3] AS [Longitude2], 
    [Join4].[Latitude3] AS [Latitude2], 
    [Join4].[Language2] AS [Language1], 
    [Join4].[IdCurrency2] AS [IdCurrency1], 
    [Join4].[CurrencyName2] AS [CurrencyName1], 
    [Join4].[Vaccine2] AS [Vaccine1], 
    [Join4].[Visa2] AS [Visa1], 
    [Join4].[Embassy2] AS [Embassy1], 
    [Join4].[Recommendations2] AS [Recommendations1], 
    [Join4].[Id4] AS [Id3], 
    [Join4].[Name3] AS [Name2], 
    [Join4].[Id5] AS [Id4], 
    [Join4].[Name4] AS [Name3], 
    [Join4].[Observations] AS [Observations], 
    [Join4].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Join4].[Web] AS [Web], 
    [Join4].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Join4].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
    [Join4].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
    [Join4].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Join4].[EmailBook] AS [EmailBook], 
    [Join4].[Cif] AS [Cif], 
    [Join4].[Contact] AS [Contact], 
    [Join4].[Account] AS [Account], 
    [Join4].[AccountIban] AS [AccountIban], 
    [Join4].[City] AS [City], 
    [Join4].[Province] AS [Province], 
    [Join4].[CorporateName] AS [CorporateName], 
    [Join4].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
    [Join4].[Code3] AS [Code2]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent1].[IdServiceType] AS [IdServiceType], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent1].[DescriptionLarge] AS [DescriptionLarge], [Extent1].[DescriptionAgency] AS [DescriptionAgency], [Extent1].[DescriptionCentral] AS [DescriptionCentral], [Extent1].[Pvp] AS [Pvp], [Extent1].[PreviousPvp] AS [PreviousPvp], [Extent1].[PriceAgency] AS [PriceAgency], [Extent1].[PriceProvider] AS [PriceProvider], [Extent1].[PriceSamurai] AS [PriceSamurai], [Extent1].[IdProvider] AS [IdProvider], [Extent1].[IdDestination] AS [IdDestination], [Extent1].[IdOrigin] AS [IdOrigin], [Extent1].[ExpirationDate] AS [ExpirationDate], [Extent1].[DistanceToCenter] AS [DistanceToCenter], [Extent1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude1], [Extent1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude1], [Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], [Extent1].[ValidationDateStart] AS [ValidationDateStart], [Extent1].[ValidationDateEnd] AS [ValidationDateEnd], [Extent1].[ExecutionDateStart] AS [ExecutionDateStart], [Extent1].[ExecutionDateEnd] AS [ExecutionDateEnd], [Extent1].[Nights] AS [Nights], [Extent1].[Document] AS [Document], [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent2].[Code] AS [Code1], [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent2].[IdSuperDestination] AS [IdSuperDestination1], [Extent2].[Iata] AS [Iata1], [Extent2].[Level] AS [Level1], [Extent2].[IdDestinationType] AS [IdDestinationType1], [Extent2].[TouristInfo] AS [TouristInfo1], [Extent2].[Longitude] AS [Longitude2], [Extent2].[Latitude] AS [Latitude2], [Extent2].[Language] AS [Language1], [Extent2].[IdCurrency] AS [IdCurrency1], [Extent2].[CurrencyName] AS [CurrencyName1], [Extent2].[Vaccine] AS [Vaccine1], [Extent2].[Visa] AS [Visa1], [Extent2].[Embassy] AS [Embassy1], [Extent2].[Recommendations] AS [Recommendations1], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent3].[Code] AS [Code2], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name2], [Extent3].[IdSuperDestination] AS [IdSuperDestination2], [Extent3].[Iata] AS [Iata2], [Extent3].[Level] AS [Level2], [Extent3].[IdDestinationType] AS [IdDestinationType2], [Extent3].[TouristInfo] AS [TouristInfo2], [Extent3].[Longitude] AS [Longitude3], [Extent3].[Latitude] AS [Latitude3], [Extent3].[Language] AS [Language2], [Extent3].[IdCurrency] AS [IdCurrency2], [Extent3].[CurrencyName] AS [CurrencyName2], [Extent3].[Vaccine] AS [Vaccine2], [Extent3].[Visa] AS [Visa2], [Extent3].[Embassy] AS [Embassy2], [Extent3].[Recommendations] AS [Recommendations2], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id4], [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name3], [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id5], [Extent5].[Name] AS [Name4], [Extent5].[Observations] AS [Observations], [Extent5].[Address] AS [Address], [Extent5].[Web] AS [Web], [Extent5].[Phone] AS [Phone], [Extent5].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], [Extent5].[Fax] AS [Fax], [Extent5].[Email] AS [Email], [Extent5].[EmailBook] AS [EmailBook], [Extent5].[Cif] AS [Cif], [Extent5].[Contact] AS [Contact], [Extent5].[Account] AS [Account], [Extent5].[AccountIban] AS [AccountIban], [Extent5].[City] AS [City], [Extent5].[Province] AS [Province], [Extent5].[CorporateName] AS [CorporateName], [Extent5].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Extent5].[Code] AS [Code3], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC) AS [row_number]
        FROM     [dbo].[Services] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Destinations] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdDestination] = [Extent2].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Destinations] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[IdOrigin] = [Extent3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ServiceTypes] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[IdServiceType] = [Extent4].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Providers] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[IdProvider] = [Extent5].[Id]
    )  AS [Join4]
    WHERE [Join4].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Join4].[Id1] DESC
```

When I remove the table "Providers" from the "From" clausule the query finish in less than a second, but if not the query take a lot of time.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the data type of the `Id` column on `Providers`? Do you get the same behaviour with just the subquery?

Comment: Have you tried using the SQL query analyzer tool? It's a built in tool

Comment: Why are you using a subquery?

Comment: All the IDs are integers. The subquery is necesary because this query is generated by a linq query that uses .skip().take()

Comment: What is your execution plan telling you. Check where your cost is. Is it doing a table scan on Providers. There is a lot of factors that can make it slow.

Comment: I've never used SQL query analyzer tool, any good tutorial?

Comment: How many rows are in the Providers table?

Comment: The providers table has 130 rows, the destination table has over 1000 and there is no problema with this table.